# Rust closure and fn mismatch

Tags: function, rust, closures

I'm trying to do something that is normal in functional language i.e. {F#, SML, OCaml, Haskel..} passing functions around as input and output.
But I think I'm not quit there yet when it comes to Rust type system. The code below is the part of my code that is making error. In short I'm making a struct that hold a function, that do something and return some other thing with possible error. The or function has the problem, since I need to incorporate that I some time in the future need to pass an input into the run function I'm using closure. I h ave tried using Fn as type but it still make the compiler through an error.

```
pub struct Pattern<T>{
   pat : fn(&str) -> Result<(T, &str),&'static str>
}

impl<T> Pattern<T> {
    pub fn run(self, input: &str) -> Result<(T,& str), &'static str> {
        (self.pat)(input)
    }

pub fn or(self, pat: Pattern<T>) -> Pattern<T> {
        Pattern {
            pat: |input| match self.run(input) {
                Ok(ret) => Ok(ret),
                Err(msg) => {
                    match pat.run(input) {
                        Ok(ret) => Ok(ret),
                        Err(msg) => Err(msg),
                    } 
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your code snipped has another issue, in the of method, you're using _pat1_ and _pat2_ variables, that are not defined.

Comment: minor typo coming from trying to make it work. but it still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not extra-confident about the solution below, but who knows...

First, in `or()` you try to provide the resulting `Pattern` a capturing
closure where a function (without capture) is expected; as you stated
in your question, a `Fn` trait seems more appropriate for the `pat` member.
In order to actually store it, `Box<dyn Fn( ...>` can be used.

Moreover, the `run()` and `or()` methods *consume* the `Pattern`s, thus
each `Pattern` can only be used once, which is probably not what you want.
I suggest using references instead.

The resulting `Pattern` in `or` is returned by value (which is correct,
in my opinion); then all the local variables its closure needs to capture
(`self` and `pat` parameters) have to be `move`d into the closure.

Since we have now many `Pattern`s referring to each others,
we have to deal explicitly with lifetimes. For example, the two `Pattern`s
combined in `or()` must outlive the resulting `Pattern`.
These constraints propagate all through the code.

Finally, an attempt was made to illustrate the usage in `main()`.

(Probably more experienced Rust programmers will find a simpler
way to achieve this, or some errors)

```rust
pub struct Pattern<'p, T> {
    pat: Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> Result<(T, &str), &'static str> + 'p>,
}

impl<'p, T> Pattern<'p, T> {
    pub fn run<'s>(
        &self,
        input: &'s str,
    ) -> Result<(T, &'s str), &'static str> {
        (self.pat)(input)
    }

    pub fn or<'a, 'b>(
        &'p self,
        pat: &'a Pattern<T>,
    ) -> Pattern<'b, T>
    where
        'p: 'b,
        'a: 'b,
    {
        Pattern {
            pat: Box::new(move |input| match self.run(input) {
                Ok(ret) => Ok(ret),
                Err(_msg) => match pat.run(input) {
                    Ok(ret) => Ok(ret),
                    Err(msg) => Err(msg),
                },
            }),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Pattern {
        pat: Box::new(|input| {
            if input.len() >= 4 {
                Ok((1, &input[0..4]))
            } else {
                Err("too short for p1")
            }
        }),
    };
    let p2 = Pattern {
        pat: Box::new(|input| {
            if input.len() >= 2 {
                Ok((2, &input[2..]))
            } else {
                Err("too short for p2")
            }
        }),
    };
    let p3 = p1.or(&p2);
    println!("p1: {:?}", p1.run("a"));
    println!("p2: {:?}", p2.run("a"));
    println!("p3: {:?}", p3.run("a"));
    println!("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    println!("p1: {:?}", p1.run("abc"));
    println!("p2: {:?}", p2.run("abc"));
    println!("p3: {:?}", p3.run("abc"));
    println!("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    println!("p1: {:?}", p1.run("abcdef"));
    println!("p2: {:?}", p2.run("abcdef"));
    println!("p3: {:?}", p3.run("abcdef"));

    /*
    p1: Err("too short for p1")
    p2: Err("too short for p2")
    p3: Err("too short for p2")
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    p1: Err("too short for p1")
    p2: Ok((2, "c"))
    p3: Ok((2, "c"))
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    p1: Ok((1, "abcd"))
    p2: Ok((2, "cdef"))
    p3: Ok((1, "abcd"))
    */
}
```

Comment: It complain about it cannot move self/pat into the closure because of it is captured by the Fn trait?

Comment: @kam I just tried again with the provided code, and it does not complain. Did you change something?

Comment: yes i didn't alter the run function but that help alot :D